# packhard bell dot s netbook ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10

sorry im absolutly linux beginner....

i bought a packhard bell netbook dots with Limpus.did not get along with limpus so wanted to install ubuntu.
netbook:
2 GB RAM intel Atom N2600, intel graphics Media Accelerator 3600
I over installled ubuntu 12.10 (desktop version) like in the instruction (isofile over USB). Installation went fine. No problems. when starting after installation alot of text is coming.....starting xyz....with alot of okays at the end of line
but nothing happends: ends with #Starting CPU interrups balancing daemon, stopping anachronics cron and blinking cursor...

was reading in this forum, tried to do some things like #recoverymode# and nomodeset...
but did not work or where do i get this graphic drivers from. Packard bell just offers windows drivers.and how do i install them?

maybe its a completely diffrent cause for this?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Same netbook here. Cannot start into X windows. Blank screen and computer freezes.

I have tried Ubuntu, slackware 14, puppy 5.4.2 , crunchbang

It works only with kernel 2.6.

The problem I think it is intel 3600 graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed it using a different ubuntu image and then successfully upgraded to 12.10.
Downloads: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/
Yeah unity 3D might be a bit slow but one can cope with it.